# Adding open source jars inside jdk using maven

Tags: maven

I want to put some jaxb jars inside the jdk so that when i compile my code the classes are taken from the jdk library instead of the war library. An d i want to do it through maven .Please help

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you'd want to change the JDK? There might be a different solution for your original problem.

Comment: actually jaxb framework comes in built with jdk 1.6, but beacuse i want to use my jaxb framework so i want my jaxb jar inside jdk so that it will replace the jdk jaxb classes

Comment: Have you tried setting the scope of the dependency to `provided`. But you have to make sure that when you deploy your war they can be found e.g. in JBoss you use some deployment descriptor file for that.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea. You'd be better advised to leave the jdk alone, and use a dependency management solution, like maven, to solve this problem.